# Audit logs for scim requests WSO2 IDP

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I want to log the **scim** requests (success,failure) that are coming to the wso2/idp server. I followed the [https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Logging+Claims+in+Audit+Logs] but the **repository\logs\audit.log** still does not contains any extra records except for a single line for the day:

'admin@carbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2019-09-17 10:45:23 ......

I also added the following to the  in the identity.xml in the hope of something getting logged..

```
http://wso2.org/claims/username
http://wso2.org/claims/userid
http://wso2.org/claims/country
http://wso2.org/claims/fullname
http://wso2.org/claims/identity/failedLoginAttempts
http://wso2.org/claims/displayName
```

But yet, no scim requests are getting logged. My scim requests are all working without any issues, except for the logging.

```
curl -v -k --user admin:admin https://localhost:9443/wso2/scim/Users/48f7cfe5-f0e3-4a67-af7e-d762aa9ab215
```

Answer (score 1):

For your use case, I think you need to log the user operations that are coming in to Identity Server. You can do it by writing a user operation event listener, you have to extend the org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserOperationEventListener class and override the methods you need to add functionality. You can override all methods of the class and simply added audit logs for them to identify the user and the particular operation he is performing. The audit logs are printed in SERVER_HOME/repository/logs/audit.log file.

Please refer the following for more details:

http://www.securityinternal.com/2016/08/user-operation-event-listener-in-wso2.html
http://www.securityinternal.com/2016/08/writing-user-operation-event-listener.html
https://github.com/thariyarox/sample-user-operation-event-listener-print-audit-logs
https://medium.com/@inthiraj1994/user-operation-event-listener-for-wso2-server-8ce4765b8c95

Comment: That would be nice way, however the username/passwd is submitted from the browser directly to the wso/idp server using a /samlsso submit. The html response from the idp is a callback form which then redirects to the webserver (if the authentication has passed). i.e. The application doesn't have programmatic access to the idp authentication.

Answer (score 0):

```
If your requirement is to get the scim logs to audit log file add the following config to 

{IS-HOME}/repository/conf/log4j.properties 

log4j.logger.org.wso2.carbon.identity.scim=DEBUG

edit the threshold value of Appender config to AUDIT_LOGFILE

log4j.appender.AUDIT_LOGFILE=org.wso2.carbon.utils.logging.appenders.CarbonDailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.AUDIT_LOGFILE.File=${carbon.home}/repository/logs/audit.log
log4j.appender.AUDIT_LOGFILE.Append=true
log4j.appender.AUDIT_LOGFILE.layout=org.wso2.carbon.utils.logging.TenantAwarePatternLayout
log4j.appender.AUDIT_LOGFILE.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %P%5p {%c}- %x %m %n
log4j.appender.AUDIT_LOGFILE.layout.TenantPattern=%U%@%D [%T] [%S]
log4j.appender.AUDIT_LOGFILE.threshold=DEBUG
log4j.additivity.AUDIT_LOG=false
```